# Can we rotate GC log based on Specific Time in JDK 8?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

I am trying GC log rotation in JDK 8. I have achieved it by using the following GC Log JVM parameter.

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:verbose-jdk8-gc.log
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:GCLogFileSize=1k
```

Additionally to that I want that the GC log rotation should also done based on a given time. Is there any parameter in JVM(JDK 8) so that I can rotate GC log based on a specific time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute `jcmd <PID> GC.rotate_log` command from an external scheduler (cron).

Comment: HI apangin Thanks for reply

Comment: Yes definitely it will solve my problem. And that is already i have implemented . But I want to know that is there any JVM Parameter for that or not ? Yes or No. That i want to know only :)

Comment: @RonakPrajapati No, there is no such JVM option. In fact, you already listed all parameters related to GC log rotations. [Here is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp#l2447) the complete list of common JVM options from JDK 8 source code.